# JavaScript: Change Div Background After Time

Tags: javascript, css, time, background-image, adsense

I have an advertisement section on my website.  For most users, this loads just fine and works as intended.  However, if the user has an ad-blocker of sorts, the advertisement doesn't show up and an empty area of the site is displayed.

My solution?  I would like to place a background image under the advertisement that asks users to consider enabling advertisements on this site only.  This image is un-obtrusive, and gives the user a choice whether or not to support the site they are visiting.  Through simple CSS, I can make this work just fine (just use background-image and it's good).

The problem is that advertisements take a little bit to load (about a second or so for some users).  I don't want this background-image to be displayed BEFORE the advertisement has a chance to load, so I'd like to change the background of the div after a certain amount of time (2-3 seconds, maybe).

Here's my current attempt at a JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_banner(){
    document.getElementById('banner').style.background="url('images/banner_bg.png')";
}
function show_banner_delay(){
    setTimeout("show_banner()", 3000);
}</script>
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="banner-wrap">
    <div id="banner">
        <!--Google AdSense Code Here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

I feel like I am probably just missing something as far as basic syntax here, but I can't seem to figure it out!

THANKS FOR ANY HELP!!!

Comment: When do you call show_banner_delay()? try dropping the () aswell

Comment: So, do you propose that I do something like: window.onload = setTimeout("show_banner", 3000);

Comment: I implemented your changes as well, but overall went with Ravan's code.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anyone using an ad blocker can almost certainly also block images (it is built-in to Adblock Plus), so they will likely block that too. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the show_banner_delay function.
Test it:

```
function show_banner(){
    document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage="url('images/banner_bg.png')";
}

window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(show_banner, 3000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `setTimeout(show_banner, 3000);`

Also, just for good measure change `...style.background = url...`  to `...style.backgroundImage = url...` unless you're going to change other attributes of the background.

Comment: I implemented your changes as well, but overall went with Ravan's code.  Thanks for your help!